# Set dynamic equal width on all elements

Tags: html, css, render

I creating a modal with some info. Sometimes I have short text, sometimes longer. I want to have good looking modal, equal modal. My project also using translation to few languages, so the strings also has different length according current language.

Can I do something for good looking modal in all cases? My first idea is set large width for `name and email class` (commented code), then works fine, all columns are equal and modal looks good. But now I am thinking about better, more universal solution. I was trying using `flex basis/shrink/grow` in some configuration, but nothing gave good effect.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.name {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
/*   width: 200px; */
}

.email {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
/*   width: 250px; */
}

.text {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>LoremIpsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <p>loremipsumloremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>LoremIpsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <p>loremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <p>loremipsumloremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <p>loremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <p>loremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use bootstrap for your requirement:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/

Comment: You want items to be aligned in both rows and columns? If that's so, have you looked into CSS Grid instead?

Comment: @IvanS95 I'm still thinking about it. Maybe just html table is also good solution?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using tables for layout, only if its used to display tabular data... but for a modal, I think its better to stick with flexbox or grids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use html `<table>` tag to solve this issue. Data displaying by map function in React, and I think my modal info's is tabular data, so I suspect `<table>` is a acceptable solution. Now every `td` element has width the same as the widest element in `table`. Solution below:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.name {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.email {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.text {
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
    </td>
    <td class="email">
     Loremipsum@dolorsit.io
    </td>
    <td class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero tempora dolore delectus dolores, et esse eum dignissimos ullam voluptas impedit veritatis neque, odio unde corporis iure dolorum consectetur est necessitatibus.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="name">
      Lorem ipsum Lorem
    </td>
    <td class="email">
     Loremipsumdolorsit@dolorsit.io
    </td>
    <td class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero tempora dolore delectus dolores, et esse eum dignissimos ullam voluptas impedit veritatis neque.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="name">
      Lorem ipsum
    </td>
    <td class="email">
     Loremipsum@dolor.io
    </td>
    <td class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For a situation like this, I generally use bootstrap javascript library. Basically bootstrap divides each row into 12 equal unit columns, and you can choose how many unit columns should your column contain.
Since we have 3 columns in each row here, we can choose 4 unit columns for each column of yours.
After adding bootstrap dependency using:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can add `col-sm-4` class to your column divs.
Also, you will notice, this will cause some text to overflow into adjacent columns, I fixed it by adding word wrap: `word-wrap: break-word;` to the row class, you can also choose to just add horizontal scroll by adding the following css to your column class:

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

Updated code would look like:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
   word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.name {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
/*   width: 200px; */
}

.email {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
/*   width: 250px; */
}

.text {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 name">
      <p>LoremIpsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 email">
      <p>loremipsumloremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 name">
      <p>LoremIpsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 email">
      <p>loremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 name">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 email">
      <p>loremipsumloremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 name">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 email">
      <p>loremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 name">
      <p>LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 email">
      <p>loremipsum@loremipsum.io</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis optio molestias obcaecati sed ipsa ea et numquam minima voluptatibus, aliquam quia at deleniti velit praesentium incidunt! Harum mollitia deleniti laudantium?Soluta voluptate ab, aliquam veniam quos placeat repudiandae enim illum rem ipsum veritatis facilis maiores dolore eveniet magni totam hic tempore reiciendis dignissimos ratione animi ea nostrum! Ducimus, perspiciatis sed!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can did it using width property:

```
.name {
    width: 20%;
}
.email {
    width: 20%;
}
.text{
    width: 60%;
}
```

try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/6bL57yd2/

of course you can change the amount as you want.